# What does 'design with capital D' mean?

Tags: terminology

Recently I have started watching/listening to the [High Resolution](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzBkNPSxw15qrW_Y8p-oCUw) podcast -- which I enjoy a lot, and there has been several occasions where the hosts or the guest has mentioned the term *design with capital D* and it sounded as it was something important to understand the context.

I was wondering what does *design with capital D* mean and perhaps a little bit on its origin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a language-based question, not a design-based one.

Comment: @Vincent thanks Vincent, that's fine. If there wasn't already an answer I would have deleted it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say something is "something with a capital S" it's just an idiom. It's not to be taken literally. It's like adding emphasis to the point that the something (or whatever it is) is very important, and is important enough figuratively speaking, to be spelled with a capital letter like a proper noun, rather than a common noun.  So "design with a capital D", basically means "important design".